# Adjusting height and width style; pixel values come out as strings

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I feel like I'm missing something crucial here when trying to edit the size (width and height) of my div "box".

When I want to see the value of height or width of "box" div I can just use `getElementById` and find the width or height, and it returns the pixel value.

`document.getElementById("box").style.height 
">> 200px"`

Nice.

However if I want to edit the number of pixel in that DIV it looks like the 200px is being returned a string and not a number, so I cannot add or subtract pixels.

```
`document.getElementById("box").style.height += 200
>>"200px200"

document.getElementById("box").style.height += 200px
>>VM1143:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

document.getElementById("box").style.height += "200px"
">>200px200px"`
```

What am I missing that I cannot edit the width and height of this div? Do I need to remove the "px" when adding and subtracting pixels?

Thanks and below is the code I am using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Day 12 - Functions 2 Computation
        </title>

        <style>
            #box {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                background-color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="group">
            <button id="bigger">Bigger</button>
            <button id="smaller">Smaller</button>
            <hr />
            <button id="blue">Blue</button>
            <button id="red">Red</button>
            <button id="green">Green</button>
            <div id="status"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="box" style="height: 200px; width: 200px"></div> <-- This one is giving me issues

        <script type="text/javascript">        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it's because style.height returns a string not an int so if you add any number to it it's going to cause an error.

You can use `offsetHeight` instead to grab the height of the element (minus the margins but including padding)

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetheight.asp

(It's offsetWidth for the width, same logic though)

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetwidth.asp

So your code would be:

```
var el = document.getElementById("box");
var height = el.offsetHeight;
var newHeight = height + 200;
el.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
```

Comment: Thanks this ended up solving my problem. I was trying to figure out a way to not have to add "px" on another line, but I guess it cannot be avoid here.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed missing something crucial; `document.getElementById("box").style.height` returns a **string**, rather than an **integer**. As such, you can't use `+=`.

You can, however, set the height manually by overwriting the string with something like `document.getElementById("box").style.height = "300px";`.

You can also use **[element.offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)** to do conditional-based adjustments:

```js
var the_box = document.getElementById("box");
var offset_height = the_box.offsetHeight;
var new_height = offset_height + 100;
the_box.style.height = new_height + 'px';

// OR

document.getElementById("box").style.height = document.getElementById("box").offsetHeight + 100 + 'px';
```

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="group">
  <button id="bigger">Bigger</button>
  <button id="smaller">Smaller</button>
  <hr />
  <button id="blue">Blue</button>
  <button id="red">Red</button>
  <button id="green">Green</button>
  <div id="status"></div>
</div>

<div id="box" style="height: 200px; width: 200px"></div>
```

Note that you need to append the `px` the end of the height once you have made the adjustment, to convert it back to a pixel-based `string`.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById().style.width` will return a valid length expression just the same as in-line style declaration. If the declaration is syntax invalid,then it will return nothing.  The width or height of an element is valid only if they are in percentage or have some length units. As for your case you have to parse the returned value. Say,you may parse it by the function `parseInt(document.getElementById("box").style.width,10)` at handy. Hope this can help you.